# How to do correct message passing between popup.js and background.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-chrome-extension

My extension should work like this:
Some data send from popup.js to background.js, in background.js I work with some web api services. And after that I send new data from background.js to popup.js for show in popup.html.

But if I after send from popup.js to background.js I close and open popup.html than data from background.js can't get popup.js because port doesn't exist.

I tried use localstorage. But my popup.html write on Vue and localsorage for Vue is not react and my data don't updates in popup.html if my popup.html was not closed/open.

How to do correct message passing?

Comment: The popup runs only when it's shown. You may need to rethink the workflow.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for VueX, which role is to store data for all the application.

https://vuex.vuejs.org/